# What does M+L in monotonicity lemma mean

Tags: petri-net

While studying a bit of petri nets I encountered on Monotonicity Lemma, which says:

> Let M and L be two markings of a net.
>
> If M->M' for a finite sequence sigma, then (M+L)->(M'+L) for every marking L.
>
> If M->for an infinite sequence sigma, then (M+L)-> for every marking L.

At the top of the arrows is sigma.

Does anyone understand what M+L mean in terms of markings? Should I add those markings together or is it a path where I add L to M?

Comment: Yes, markings are often identified with vectors of integers. Adding two markings results in a new marking where the number of tokens for each place is the sum of numbers of tokens for this place in the two markings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not really sure about it.